# How does one call the function "createNewNode" in a link list to insert it into another function called "pushFront"?

Tags: c++

While trying to call a function called `creatNewNode()` in another function called `pushFront()`, I'm supposed to pass two parameters, but I do not know what it wants me to pass. Having tried to figure it out, nothing worked.

Here is the code:

```
struct SingleLinkedListNode {
    int value;              //Integer value of the node
    SingleLinkedListNode* next = 0; //Pointer to the next node in the list
                //Next pointer is initialized to NULL
};

struct SingleLinkedList {
    SingleLinkedListNode* head = 0; //Pointer to the beginning of the list
    SingleLinkedListNode* tail = 0; //Pointer to the end of the list
    int size = 0;           //Counts the number of nodes in the list
};

SingleLinkedListNode* createNewNode(const int value, SingleLinkedListNode* next) {
    SingleLinkedListNode* n = new SingleLinkedListNode;
    n -> value = value;
    n -> next = next;

    return n;
}

void pushFront(SingleLinkedList& list, const int value) {
    //id the list is empty
    if (list.head == NULL) {          
        n = createNewNode(value, //I dont know);
        list.head -> n;
        n -> list.tail;
    }
    //else there is already a nod in the list
    else {
        n = createNewNode(value,);
        
        list.head -> n;
        n -> next      
    }
}
```

Comment: In C++, the preference is to use `nullptr` instead of 0 for pointers.

Comment: A *push* operation needs to have the node data and a pointer to the list to insert into.

Comment: I highly recommend using pen and paper and drawing the linked list as you go through each line of the code.  A debugger will be very useful too.

Comment: What do you think bare expressions like this are doing? `list.head -> n;`  `n -> list.tail;`

Comment: `->` is not some kind of assignment operator. `list.head -> n` is the same as `list.head->n` which is the same as: `(*list.head).n`

Comment: As you've asked about C++, `createNewNode` should just be a constructor for `SingleLinkedListNode `.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the second argument to `createNewNode` needs to be either `nullptr` if the list is empty, or `list.head` if it's not. In the first case we also need to update `list.tail` as well as `list.head`.

You'll also want to update `list.size`.

```
void pushFront(SingleLinkedList& list, const int value) {
    if (list.head == nullptr) {          
        auto n = createNewNode(value, nullptr);
        list.head = n;
        list.tail = n;
        list.size = 1;
    }
    else {
        auto n = createNewNode(value, list.head);
        
        list.head = n;
        list.size++; 
    }
}
```

Of course, since this is C++, `createNewNode` should be a constructor for the `LinkedListNode` struct.

```
struct SingleLinkedListNode {
    int value;              
    SingleLinkedListNode* next = nullptr; 
  
    SingleLinkedListNode(int value, SingleLinkedListNode *next=nullptr)
    : value(value), next(next)
    { }
};
```

And `pushFront` should be a member function of the `SingleLinkedList` struct.

```
struct SingleLinkedList {
    SingleLinkedListNode *head = nullptr; 
    SingleLinkedListNode *tail = nullptr; 
    int size = 0; 

    void pushFront(int value) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            auto n = new SingleLinkedListNode(value);

            head = n;
            tail = n;
            size = 1;
        }
        else {
            auto n = new SingleLinkedListNode(value, head);

            head = n;
            size++;
        }
    }         
};
```

Of course, nodes are an implementation detail of a list, so:

```
struct SingleLinkedList {
    private:
    struct Node {
        int value;              
        Node *next = nullptr; 
  
        Node(int value, Node *next=nullptr)
        : value(value), next(next)
        { } 
    };
    
    public:
    Node *head = 0; 
    Node *tail = 0; 
    int size = 0; 

    void pushFront(int value) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            auto n = new Node(value);

            head = n;
            tail = n;
            size = 1;
        }
        else {
            auto n = new Node(value, head);

            head = n;
            size++;
        }
    }         
};
```

Further problem is that deleting a list will leave dangling pointers to all of those nodes, so we need a destructor.

*Of course, you also need to think about move and copy behaviors, so review [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).*

```
struct SingleLinkedList {
    private:
    struct Node {
        int value;              
        Node *next = nullptr; 
  
        Node(int value, Node *next=nullptr)
        : value(value), next(next)
        { } 
    };
    
    public:
    Node *head = 0; 
    Node *tail = 0; 
    int size = 0; 

    ~SingleLinkedList() {
        Node *itr = head;

        while (itr) {
            Node *temp = itr->next;
            delete itr;
            itr = temp;
        }
    }

    void pushFront(int value) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            auto n = new Node(value);

            head = n;
            tail = n;
            size = 1;
        }
        else {
            auto n = new Node(value, head);

            head = n;
            size++;
        }
    }         
};
```

Aside from rule of three/five/zero issues, you probably want to hide the head and tail nodes, as well as the size to prevent unwanted modification. Of course, if all of the implementation details are hidden, you probably want to expose an iterator.

```
template <typename T>
struct SingleLinkedList {
    private:
    struct Node {
        T value;
        Node *next = nullptr;

        Node(T value, Node *next=nullptr)
        : value(value), next(next)
        { }
    };

    struct Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
        Node *cur;

        Iterator(Node *cur) : cur(cur) { }
        Iterator(const Iterator& i) : cur(i.cur) { }

        Iterator& operator++() {
            cur = cur->next;
            return *this;
        }

        Iterator operator++(T) {
            Iterator tmp(*this);
            operator++();
            return tmp;
        }

        bool operator==(const Iterator& i) const {
            return cur == i.cur;
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator& i) const {
            return cur != i.cur;
        }

        T& operator*() { return cur->value; }
    };

    Node *head = 0;
    Node *tail = 0;
    int size = 0;

    public:
    ~SingleLinkedList() {
        Node *itr = head;

        while (itr) {
            Node *temp = itr->next;
            delete itr;
            itr = temp;
        }
    }

    std::size_t getSize() const { return size; }

    bool empty() const {
        return head == nullptr;
    }

    void pushFront(T value) {
        if (empty()) {
            auto n = new Node(value);

            head = n;
            tail = n;
            size = 1;
        }
        else {
            auto n = new Node(value, head);

            head = n;
            size++;
        }
    }

    Iterator begin() const { return Iterator(head); }
    Iterator end() const { return nullptr; }
};
```

Comment: The pushFront logic can be simplified further